# Groovy wslite.rest.RestClient post or put results in a 411 Length Required Error

Tags: rest, groovy

Using the `wslite.rest.RestClient`, if I use `post` or `put`, I'm getting a 411 Length Required error returned from the service. I've added the header `Content-Length: (size)` but I still get an error. Does anyone have suguestions? Here's the code for a `put` request:

```
        def builder = new JsonBuilder()
        // required json data
        def root = builder {
            "ActivationDate" "\\/Date(1434563608000-0500)\\/"
            "EmailAddress" "ebaa@gmail.com"
            "ExpirationDate" "\\/Date(1435686808000-0500)\\/"
            "FirstName" "ebaa"
            "LastName" "ebaa"
            "MiddleName" "ebaa"
            "OtherName" "ebaa"
            "Password" "abc12345"
            "Status" 1
        }

        RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient('https://serviceBaseUrl')
        Response response

        try {
            restClient.authorization = new HTTPBasicAuthorization(username: 'user', password: 'pass')
            restClient.defaultCharset = 'UTF-8'
            restClient.defaultContentTypeHeader = 'application/json'
            restClient.defaultAcceptHeader = 'application/json'

            response = restClient.put(path: "/Location/${locName}/Administrator/${name}", 
                headers:['Accept': 'application/json', 
                    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Connection':'keep-alive', 'Pragma':'no-cache', 'Cache-Control':'no-cache', 
                    'Content-Length': builder.toString().length()], 
                    data: builder.toPrettyString().getBytes())

            return response.json
        } catch(ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I've also tried changing the data: param to body, but I get the same response. Also, If I use the Firefox plugin, HttpRequester (https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) and make the same request, I get a 200 status code and the appropriate data is updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For `put` or `post` it is expecting the payload to be in a closure.  Try the following, this should send the data and automatically set the right `Content-Length`:

```
....
....
response = restClient.put(
              path: "/Location/${locName}/Administrator/${name}", 
              headers:['Accept': 'application/json',
                       'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5', 
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                       'Connection':'keep-alive', 
                       'Pragma':'no-cache', 
                       'Cache-Control':'no-cache']) 
    {
        text builder.toPrettyString()            
        //bytes builder.toPrettyString().bytes  // or as bytes
        //json 'ActivationDate': '...', 'EmailAddress': '...'  // or a json string from a map
    }
```

See the [Sending Content](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#sending-content) section of the README.

Comment: Perfect! I was getting a "400 Bad Request" when I tried that earlier. Seems my escaped backslashes \\ are not liked by the server around the dates. Appreciate the help! Thanks John!